# When to use (" " , : ; ' ! . ) in sentence. What is exactly significance?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

Kindly enlighten on query to understand following terms.

I will be really thankful.

Comment: All of those punctuation marks can be explained by searching for the exact mark (not even its name) in Wikipedia.

Comment: [: (colon)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29) and [. (fullstop)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullstop) cannot, but the rest can.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I was missing the word "punctuation". I have found after searching this like "http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/marks.htm", I think it would be useful.   thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Quotation marks: " "

This form of punctuation has a number of meanings. The most common use of quotation marks is to indicate that the enclosed text has been spoken.

> "Good morning, everyone," said John. "There are several topics I would like to talk about in this meeting."

Here, John is actually saying the words out loud, so this is indicated with quotation marks. Some fonts use curved quotation marks like in the title of this question, but they are functionally no different from the straight variation.

Another common use of quotation marks is to show that the use of a word isn't the standard meaning. This may be a colloquialism, but sometimes is used to emphasize an ironic term.

> These so-called "smart" phones are pretty dumb.

In this sentence, the phone is actually called a *smart phone*, but we're emphasizing the irony in calling it *smart* by enclosing that word in quotation marks.

The third most common use of quotation marks is to indicate a quote from another source. (This is, actually, the origin of the name *quotation* marks.)

> My favorite Shakespearean monologue is *Hamlet*'s "to be or not to be."

In this example, Shakespeare wrote a monologue that begins with the words "To be, or not to be, that is the question." Here we indicate that the words are not our own by using quotation marks.

There are other uses for quotation marks, but these are the most common.

### Apostrophe: '

The apostrophe is most commonly used to indicate possessiveness. In the English language, the singular possessive is usually indicated by appending *'s*, while the plural possessive is usually indicated by appending *'* after the already-present *s*.

> the dog's bark
>
> the cat's meow
>
> John's car
>
> the birds' song
>
> the drummers' drums
>
> the foxes' fur

If a word doesn't end in *s* in its plural form, it also usually forms the possessive by appending *'s*.

> the children's toys

Another common use of apostrophes is to form contractions. Certain words can be combined into a shortened form, called a contraction:

> can not = can't
>
> will not = won't
>
> shall not = shan't
>
> could have = could've
>
> would have = would've
>
> should have = should've

Forming contractions and the possessive form is the most common use of this particular form of punctuation. However, another common use is to indicate that a letter is missing from a word. This is usually used when indicating dialect, as many regional dialects include dropping the sounds from particular words.

> "I heard nothin'," said Tom.

Here, the word is *nothing*, but Tom pronounces it by dropping the final hard G sound at the end.

One final common use of the apostrophe is to indicate a quotation within a quotation.

> "I tried to order a coffee at the shop," said Jane. "But the clerk just laughed and said, 'Sorry, we're out of coffee.'"

### Exclamation point: !

The exclamation point is used at the end of a sentence or an interjection to indicate excitement. In some literature, it can also be used to indicate shouting.

> Wow! I never knew you could run so fast!
>
> Stop, thief!